# YouTube Embed API doesn't autoplay on mobile

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

It seems like YouTube Embed API doesn't autoplay anymore on mobile devices. I had used in a webpage in which was working fine but since ends of July it broken. I tested the [API Reference Example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=es-419) and the same happens.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

this is how to fix it. The only reason why it doesn't work is because google developers shut it off, so change the default off in google autoplay policy.